# How do you record RTSP Stream using MobileVLCKit IOS?

Tags: ios, vlc, rtsp, libvlc, vlckit

So I currently have a RTSP Stream that is ran with the MobileVLCKit library's. I am able to receive the video stream with no problem, what I need to do now is record that RTSP stream onto the iPhone its being streamed to. Essentially I need to save the incoming RTSP stream to the phone while also letting the user view it live.

Comment: Have you found a solution?